# Getting Android Contacts Cursor Exception

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get a contact's number that the user selects. The problem is, whenever a contact is selected from the list, it throws this exception :

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

This occurs with any contact, even those with multiple phone numbers.

The only examples that opened the contact list for me :

[Pick a Number and Name From Contacts List in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496350/pick-a-number-and-name-from-contacts-list-in-android-app)

[How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

[Android contacts database giving me an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794070/android-contacts-database-giving-me-an-exception)

They all produce the same error for me.

My code :

Calling the intent

```
public void pickPerson(View V)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                               ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

Getting the phone number

```
//Declcared earlier
static final int PICK_CONTACT=1;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) 
    {
        case (PICK_CONTACT) :
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) 
                {
                    String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                              null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER));
                        phone.setText(cNumber); //EditText view
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat :

```
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1051 flg=0x1 }} to activity {somebadger.textspammer/somebadger.textspammer.Main}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3208)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3251)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at somebadger.textspammer.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:76)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5344)
11-29 12:35:17.770: E/AndroidRuntime(26254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3204)
```

Comment: Add your logcat message here..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));`

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
public class ReadContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    private ListView contactsList;

    private Context cntx;
    private Constant constants;

    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, // 0
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, // 1
        Contacts.STARRED, // 2
        Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED, // 3
        Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE, // 4
        Contacts.PHOTO_ID, // 5
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, // 6
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, // 7
    };

    private long contactId;
    private String display_name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    private ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>contactWrap = new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>();
    private HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>map = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>>();

    private ContactsAdapter adapter;

    private DataController controller;

    public ReadContacts(Context cntx, ListView contactList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx = cntx;
        constants = new Constant();
        this.contactsList = contactList;

        controller = DataController.getInstance(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
             constants.displayProgressDialog(cntx, "Loading Contacts...", "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(!(controller.contactWrapper.size()>0))
        {
        try {
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

            Cursor c = cntx.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                    null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

            int colorcounter = 0;
            String[] colorcounter_array = { "#91A46B", "#8BB6B5", "#CAA973", "#8DA6C8","#D19B8D"};

            int color_string;
            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
            {
//              contactWrap.clear();
                try {
                    contactId = 0;
                    String hasPhone = "";
                    display_name = "";
                    phoneNumber = "";

                    c.moveToPosition(i);

                    contactId =  c.getLong(0);
                    display_name = c.getString(1);
                    hasPhone = c.getString(7);

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;

                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            int indexPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);
                            String phoneType =  phones.getString(indexPhoneType);

                            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)); 

                            String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                            if (colorcounter < 5) 
                            {
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            } else {
                                colorcounter = 0;
                                color_string =Color.parseColor(colorcounter_array[colorcounter]);
                                colorcounter++;
                            }
                            contactWrap.add(new ContactsWrapper(contactId, display_name, phoneNumber,lookupKey,false,color_string));
                        }
//                      map.put(contactId, new ArrayList<ContactsWrapper>(contactWrap));
                        phones.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            }
            controller.contactWrapper = contactWrap;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        constants.dismissDialog();

        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(cntx);
        contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

and this is my contact wrapper class

```
public class ContactsWrapper {

private long contactId;
private String displayName,displayNumber,lookUp;
public boolean checked = true;
int color_string;

public ContactsWrapper(long contactId, String displayName, String displayNumber, String lookUp, boolean checked,int color_string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.contactId = contactId;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.displayNumber = displayNumber;
    this.lookUp = lookUp;
    this.checked = checked;
    this.color_string =color_string;
}

public String getLookUp() {
    return lookUp;
}

public int getColor_string() {
    return color_string;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public long getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}

public String getDisplayNumber() {
    return displayNumber;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}
}
```

Comment: How would I use this? I'm newer to andriod programming. But when I used the ReadContacts class, eclipse cannot find the Constants, DataController and ContactsAdapter classes.